# Raspberry has internet access but can't connect to SSH or webserver

Tags: ssh, internet, docker

My Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to the router via cable. To this day, I had no issues with it, I was running home assistant on it (and developing a few additions on my own). However, while I was waiting for my docker composer to start, the process got stuck on the network creation (my dockers are using a custom network, so I can set a fix IP to them). I waited hours, but it was still stuck. So, I had to reset the Pi manually, but after that I was not able to log back into SSH.

What I tried:

1. Logging into the Pi and rebooting it. This got another error, as boot started hanging at the following step: `Stopped containerd container runtime`, I had to manually reset.
2. Pulling the network cable and putting it back.
3. Running `ifconfig`, the resulting IP is what I set in the router
4. Pinging the Pi, no response

I am running out of ideas, maybe someone has seen a problem like this before. I really hope that the problem is not caused by a corrupted SD card (again)

Comment: I had RPi 3B/B+, running for 10 yrs and no problem

Answer (score 0):

I was right, the SD card was faulty again, I needed to reinstall it, now it works.